# Pagination in MyBatis using PageHelper gives no improvement in time

Tags: java, pagination, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to use PageHelper plugin provided on [this repo](https://github.com/pagehelper/Mybatis-PageHelper) following the installation instructions provided [here](https://github.com/pagehelper/Mybatis-PageHelper/blob/master/wikis/en/HowToUse.md), but my problem is that I am unable to achieve better timings as compared to what I was getting without the plugin. I downloaded jars for pagehelper and jsqparser, added them to the build path of my project as well as added pagehelper in dependencies list in build.gradle of my project as:

```
 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.github.pagehelper:pagehelper:3.2.1'
     compile files("lib/jsqlparser-3.0.jar")
}
```

and added them to my build path as well. Then for the second step, I edited config `org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean` as following:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="wrapperDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/MapConfig.xml"/>
    <property name="plugins">
    <array>
      <bean class="com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor">
        <property name="properties">
          <!-- config params as the following -->
          <value>
            helperDialect=mysql
            reasonable=true
            supportMethodsArguments=true
            params=count=countSql
            autoRuntimeDialect=true
          </value>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </array>
  </property>
</bean>
```

where the first two properties were already present in this xml file. Now after making these changes, I build my project and run it using jetty by calling selectList in the following manner:

```
RowBounds rowBounds = new RowBounds(0, 100);
List<E> pendingRequests = getSqlSession().<E>selectList("fetchAllPendingRequests",inputData,rowBounds);
```

where E is the datatype of my results.

The problem is that the time I get for this function to fetch all the results using the PageHelper plugin is almost the same as that I get without using the plugin. Although when I go into the debugging mode, I see that in both the cases, the query from database is happening in different ways through different methods. While without using the plugin, the final query call is made using `executor` object in SimpleExecutor class, using the plugin the call is made from PageInterceptor class of the PageHelper repo. So the only conclusion I draw is it is unable to perform physical pagination despite making use of the plugin, but I could not understand the reasons for it.
Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Please, enable SQL queries logging in mybatis or in the database and check what queries are sent to the DB. Also why do you expect to have an improvement in the performance? How do you measure the execution time? What time results do you get for both cases? How many records are returned in both cases? Without answers to this questions it is hard to help you.

Comment: @RomanKonoval I check the performance as the time taken by my function to fetch the number of records required with and without using the PageHelper plugin. I expect better performance using the PageHelper plugin since as the link I provided in the question mentioned that using PageHelper plugin, we can achieve physical pagination which is better than logical pagination otherwise, actually going through all the rows and then returning the number of results we want.

Comment: @RomanKonoval also it takes like 50s to fetch around 50 results, 1.7 mins to fetch around 100 for both the cases.